# Добавляется слэш при подключении скриптов в yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключаю скрипты в yii2.
Все правильно ли я делаю? Раюотаю с этим фреймворком недавно.
Добавляется слеш перед 'web', который не позволяет найти js файл, скрипты не работают. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Вы в `$css` и `$js` сами пишите `/web` и удивляетесь, что он добавляется в html. Странно, не находите?))

Надо указать относительный путь. Попробуйте так:

```
public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
// public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END]; // - если надо

public $css = [ 
    'css/style.js',
];

public $js = [
    'js/app.js',
];

public $depends = [
    // dependencies
];
```

Comment: Я исправил это, но на остальных страницах не подключаются скрипты, а только стили. Что делать?

Comment: Надо ассет на тех страницах подключать. Либо этот ассет подключить в /views/layouts/main.php

Comment: Подключил ассет в /views/layouts/pixargrid.php(это мой основной layout), но опять же скрипты не работают.

Comment: значит app js не там лежит

Comment: Все подключил, все лежит на местах но выдает ошибку - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Это значит что в пыхе ошибка. Например не подключен неймспейс. Или вообще в контроллере ошибка...... читайте **ВСЕ** мои ответы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482

Comment: А какой namespace нужно сюда подключить? У меня не подключен ни один namespace в файле.

Comment: `use app\assets\AppAsset;  AppAsset::register($this);` ..... могу только сказать, что учите PHP в таком случае и фреймворк и работу с фреймворком. А также работайте в IDE, у которого есть автодополнение и сам втыкает за вас неймспейсы...... больше смысла чего-то обсуждать не вижу. Ответ дан. А основам языка учить в комментариях я не горю желанием))