# Стили подключаются к основной странице, а к другой странице нет

Tags: php, yii2

**Пишу на фреймворке Yii2. В файле AppAssets подключаю стили и скрипты. На основной странице все отлично работает. Но на других, в папке site, при переходе на файл ошибка, стили и скрипты не обрабатываются из-за нее. Что можно сделать с этим. Возможно нужно подключить namespace, но какой, если это так.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пути относительные.

Comment: А какой тип нужен? Абсолютный?

Comment: Либо абсолютный, либо правильно посчитанный относительно текущей страницы, либо относительный с тегом base, что популярно для SPA.

Comment: А как это можно реализовать и где? Я недавно  работаю с этим фреймворком.  Спасибо за ваши советы!

Comment: Понятия не имею - я не работаю ни с ним, ни вообще с php.

Comment: ёшкин матрёшкин...... вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1286846/191482  вы писали `@webroot` и `@web` и даже ответ  там тоже с собачками...... а тут без собаки.....ну вы посмотрите в Yii как там пишется правильно  .........вот же документация https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets#:~:text=An%20asset%20in%20Yii%20is,preferable%20to%20manage%20assets%20programmatically.   а вот на русском https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/structure-assets/